# WebGrid pagination issue in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, paging, webgrid

The issue is that pagination is working fine till the 9th page number and when I request the page which is in double or more digits then it takes the last digits and ignore the rest, **say e.g. If I request a page number 10 then it displays the page 0 by passing "?page=0" as query string and discards the 1 and if I request a page number say e.g. 458 then it shows the page number 8 by passing "?page=8" as query string and discards the 45 from 458.**
Here is my code:

**In Javacsript:**

```
        $(function () {
    $('tfoot a').click(function () {
        // try to extract the page number from the link
        var page = this.href.match(/page=([0-9])+/)[1];

        // submit the form so that the POST action is invoked
        var form = document.forms[0];
        form.action = '/Session/Index?page=' + page;
        form.submit();

        return false;
    });
});
      </script>
```

**In view:**

```
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.ListSessions, rowsPerPage: 5,
    canPage: true, canSort: false, defaultSort: "Absentee");

     @grid.GetHtml(
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
                            grid.Column(format: @<text> <input type="hidden" id="ColorCodeValue" name="ColorCodeValue" value="@item.ColorCodeValue" /> </text>, style: "width:0px;"),
                            grid.Column("CreatedBy", "Created By"),
                            grid.Column("Session Title", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink((string)item.SessionTitle, MVC.Session.ActionNames.EditSession,
                            new { id = item.SessionId })),
                            grid.Column("SessionID", "Simple Session ID"),
                            grid.Column("StartDate", "Start Date"),
                            grid.Column("StartTime", "Start Time"),                               
                            grid.Column("SessionStatus", "Status"),
                            grid.Column("Prep Materials", format: @<text><a  onclick="SessionClick();" id="@item.EnableViewLink" href="@Url.Action(MVC.Session.Actions.ViewSession((string)item.SessionID))">View</a><a id="UploadSessionMaterial"  href="@Url.Action(MVC.Session.Actions.UploadSession((Int32)item.SessionId))">Upload</a>  </text>),
                            grid.Column("Action", format: @<text><a   href="@Url.Action(MVC.Session.Actions.ViewSession((int)item.SessionId))">View</a><a id="@item.IsPublished" class="@item.IsTranscriptExists" href="@Url.Action(MVC.Session.Actions.EditTranscript((Int32)item.SessionId))">Edited Session </a></text>)
                                     ), mode: WebGridPagerModes.All)
```

**and in Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Index(SessionViewModel model)
    {
        model = GetSessionListing(model);
        return View(model);
    }


    private SessionViewModel GetSessionListing(SessionViewModel model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            model = new SessionViewModel();
        }
        int page = 1;
        if (Convert.ToInt64( Request["page"]) != null)
            int.TryParse(Request["page"], out page);

        //Rest of Coding here           

        return model;
    }
```

Any help would be great!
If you still need to ask something more then please ask me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try to extract the page number from the link
var page = this.href.match(/page=([0-9])+/)[1];
```

Correct:

```
// try to extract the page number from the link
var page = this.href.match(/page=([0-9]+)/)[1];
```

You need that "+" inside the "()" because that "+" is required on the match pattern and not the pattern group for what you are trying to do here.

Regular expressions are always tricky!!

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have shared doesn't give enough of information to help troubleshoot this. I think the problem might be somewhere in the code where you are submitting the request to load next page numbers in your web grid. And as you have yourself mentioned:

*

> "say e.g. If I request a page number 10 then it displays the page 0 by
>   passing "?page=0" as query string and discards the 1 "

*

I think the problem is really where your request/querystring gets formed! You may share that piece of code to help identify the issue.

Comment: Hello @Nagesh Chopra, Thanks for your reply, Please see my code once again I have updated it as I forget to post the code were I am requesting the page.